# jOOQ - nested object with many to many relationship

Tags: java, many-to-many, one-to-many, jooq

I've been trying to figure out how to convert nested objects from a jOOQ query.
I've seen the RecordMapper or java 8 streams mentioned as possible solutions but have trouble figuring out how I could use those.

My objects look similar to this, with Student-Teacher being a N:N relationship and Student-Book a 1:N.

```
Student {
  List<Teacher> teachers
  List<Book> books;
}
```

Now I want to query the tables using jooq and convert that to a Student object that contains the others. Is there a straight forward way to do this? Are there examples that show how to achieve this?
Is intoGroups usable with a schema similar to this? If I do intoGroups do I get a list of all the different types of records that I joined the database with?

I could also do 2 queries, that shouldn't really be a problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Before jOOQ 3.14

Historically, jOOQ did not offer any mapping solutions for many-to-many relationships. It is not easy to achieve using flat result sets originating from SQL joins, where cartesian products between unrelated entities (in your case: between `Teacher` and `Book`) are not uncommon.

Solutions using 2 or more queries are possible, but there's a lot of hand written mapping code that one would like to avoid.

#### After jOOQ 3.14

Starting from [jOOQ 3.14 and the new SQL/XML and SQL/JSON support](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/), this will be possible relatively easily. In essence, you will be using your RDBMS's native XML or JSON support to nest collections directly in SQL.

You can write a query like this (assuming you use the code generator):

```java
List<Student> students =
ctx.select(jsonObject(
     jsonEntry("name", STUDENT.NAME),
     jsonEntry("id", STUDENT.ID),
     jsonEntry("teachers", field(
       select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(TEACHER.NAME, TEACHER.ID)))
       .from(TEACHER)
       .join(STUDENT_TEACHER).on(TEACHER.ID.eq(STUDENT_TEACHER.TEACHER_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_TEACHER.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     )),
     jsonEntry("books", field(
       select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(BOOK.NAME, BOOK.ID)))
       .from(BOOK)
       .join(STUDENT_BOOK).on(BOOK.ID.eq(STUDENT_BOOK.BOOK_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_BOOK.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     ))
   ))
   .from(STUDENT)
   .fetchInto(Student.class);
```

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

#### After jOOQ 3.15

jOOQ finally has [`MULTISET` support, see #3884](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3884) or [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/). This allows for simplifying the above JSON approach:

**Using reflection mapping**

```java
List<Student> students =
ctx.select(
     STUDENT.NAME,
     STUDENT.ID,
     multiset(
       select(TEACHER.NAME, TEACHER.ID)
       .from(TEACHER)
       .join(STUDENT_TEACHER)
         .on(TEACHER.ID.eq(STUDENT_TEACHER.TEACHER_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_TEACHER.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     ).as("teachers").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Teacher.class)),
     multiset(
       select(BOOK.NAME, BOOK.ID)
       .from(BOOK)
       .join(STUDENT_BOOK).on(BOOK.ID.eq(STUDENT_BOOK.BOOK_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_BOOK.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     ).as("books").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Book.class))
   ))
   .from(STUDENT)
   .fetchInto(Student.class);
```

**Using type-safe, reflection free mapping**

Much better than using reflection would be if you had immutable DTOs (e.g. Java 16 records), in case of which you could map jOOQ records directly into constructor references, in a type-safe, compile-time checked, reflection free way:

```java
List<Student> students =
ctx.select(
     STUDENT.NAME,
     STUDENT.ID,
     multiset(
       select(TEACHER.NAME, TEACHER.ID)
       .from(TEACHER)
       .join(STUDENT_TEACHER)
         .on(TEACHER.ID.eq(STUDENT_TEACHER.TEACHER_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_TEACHER.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     ).as("teachers").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Teacher::new))),
     multiset(
       select(BOOK.NAME, BOOK.ID)
       .from(BOOK)
       .join(STUDENT_BOOK).on(BOOK.ID.eq(STUDENT_BOOK.BOOK_ID))
       .where(STUDENT_BOOK.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
     ).as("books").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Book::new)))
   ))
   .from(STUDENT)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Student::new));
```