# Load PostgreSQL tree with jOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have the following structure in PostgreSQL:

```
TableA has many TableB has many TableC
```

These three tables (simplified) are as follows:

```
create table TableA (
   idA int,
   nameA varchar(100));


create table TableB (
   idA int,
   idB int,
   nameB varchar(100));


create table TableC (
   idA int,
   idB int,
   idC int,
   nameC varchar(100));
```

I need to run with jOOQ on PostgreSQL a select of `TableA`, but it should also load any related rows from `TableB` and `TableC`. Is there a way to run a single jOOQ statement to load this tree? I know that I could do this with `join`s, but I'm trying to avoid any loops in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.15 solution using `MULTISET`

Starting with jOOQ 3.15, you can nest collections using the [standard SQL `MULTISET` operator, which is emulated using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/)

```sql
var result =
ctx.select(
      TABLE_A.ID_A, TABLE_A.NAME_A,
      multiset(
        select(
          TABLE_B.ID_B, TABLE_B.NAME_B,
          multiset(
            select(TABLE_C.ID_C, TABLE_C.NAME_C)
            .from(TABLE_C)
            .where(TABLE_C.ID_B.eq(TABLE_B.ID_B))
            .and(TABLE_C.ID_A.eq(TABLE_B.ID_A))
          ).as("c")
        )
        .from(TABLE_B)
        .where(TABLE_B.ID_A.eq(TABLE_A.ID_A))
      ).as("b")
    )
   .from(TABLE_A)
   .fetch();
```

The type of `result` is inferred to:

```java
Result<Record3<
  Integer,          // TABLE_A.ID_A
  String,           // TABLE_A.NAME_A
  Result<Record3< 
    Integer,        // TABLE_B.ID_B
    String,         // TABLE_B.NAME_B
    Result<Record2<
      Integer,      // TABLE_C.ID_C
      String        // TABLE_C.NAME_C
    >>
  >>
>> result = ...
```

If you prefer to map this into some custom DTO data structure, e.g.

```java
record TableC(int idC, String nameC) {}
record TableB(int idB, String nameB, List<TableC> c) {}
record TableA(int idA, String nameA, List<TableB> b) {}
```

You can do this easily using [jOOQ 3.15's new ad-hoc conversion feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/):

```sql
List<TableA> result =
ctx.select(
      TABLE_A.ID_A, TABLE_A.NAME_A,
      multiset(
        select(
          TABLE_B.ID_B, TABLE_B.NAME_B,
          multiset(
            select(TABLE_C.ID_C, TABLE_C.NAME_C)
            .from(TABLE_C)
            .where(TABLE_C.ID_B.eq(TABLE_B.ID_B))
            .and(TABLE_C.ID_A.eq(TABLE_B.ID_A))
          ).as("c").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(TableC::new)))
        )
        .from(TABLE_B)
        .where(TABLE_B.ID_A.eq(TABLE_A.ID_A))
      ).as("b").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(TableB::new)))
    )
   .from(TABLE_A)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(TableA::new));
```

All of the mappings are type safe, compile time checked, and reflection free

#### jOOQ 3.14 solution using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON

You can use jOOQ 3.14's SQL/XML or SQL/JSON support for this, [see this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support)

If you have Gson or Jackson on the classpath, they can be used to map the XML or JSON structure back to your Java class hierarchies. An example for that is given on the [manual's page about `ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/)

Essentially:

```sql
ctx.select(
     jsonObject(
       key("idA").value(TABLE_A.ID_A),
       key("nameA").value(TABLE_A.NAME_A),
       key("b").value(
         select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
           key("idB").value(TABLE_B.ID_B),
           key("nameB").value(TABLE_B.NAME_B),
           key("c").value(
             select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
               key("idC").value(TABLE_C.ID_C),
               key("nameC").value(TABLE_C.NAME_C)
             )))
             .from(TABLE_C)
             .where(TABLE_C.ID_B.eq(TABLE_B.ID_B))
           )
         )))
         .from(TABLE_B)
         .where(TABLE_B.ID_A.eq(TABLE_A.ID_A))
       )
     )
   )
   .from(TABLE_A)
   .fetch();
```

See also related questions here:

- [jOOQ - nested object with many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63207665/521799)
- [jooq single query with one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33845239/521799)
- [JOOQ pojos with one-to-many and many-to-many relations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23329127/521799)

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)